# How to get todays total by excluding yesterdays collection

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have database fields `bill_amount`, `paid_amount`, `due_amount`..if a customer created with `bill_amount`, `paid_amount` & `due_amount` &  like 240, 200 & 40. and the next day he cleared the amount ie, paid_amount become 240 & due_amount becomes 0 .
If i tried to get report of daily collection which is daily paid_amount where yesteday paid_amount shouldn't be added .means todays collection should be 40 not 240..How do i track it in sql?

the following sql query returns todays sum of todays paid_amount but it includes the yesterdays amount also..how to exclude the yesterdays `paid_amount`for same customer?

```
 $daily_collection_m = DB::select("SELECT sum(transactions.paid_amount) as daily_collection_m FROM  transactions  
            WHERE CAST(transactions.created_at as DATE) ='$day' ;
```

Comment: use another table where you store the paid amount per day (day - amount paid - transaction id) and voila!

Comment: simply query the db for today's records only. in your WHERE clause "date = ".date("Y-m-d");